# making vim fold also hide newline after function

Tags: vim

How can one make vim's fold function - when using foldmethod=syntax - also hide one newline after each function, if-else and struct (using Go).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how to do it for C:

- Take the original syntax file (under Unix, typically found in `/usr/share/vim`) and copy it to (again, under Unix) `~/.vim/syntax`.
- Change the "end" pattern in the cBlock region definition:

```
syntax region cBlock    start="{" end="}" transparent fold
```

becomes

```
syntax region cBlock    start="{" end="}\(\n\n\)\?" transparent fold
```

Here, the first `\n` matches the newline character immediately following the closing brace, the second one the empty line. 
This will not work if `}` is followed by e.g. a comment: the block will still fold, but the following newline will not.

I do not have a syntax file for Go here (as far as I can tell), but it should work in a similar way.

Note: the more flexible way would be to create a new file at `~/.vim/after/syntax` and just change the region definition, but I have been unsuccessful here. Merely copying the region definition does not work.